# Case-folded sorting of output columns containing expressions

Tags: postgresql, order-by, sorting, case-sensitive

Using the following query as simple example,

```
    SELECT  l.id,
            string_agg(lc.country, ' ' ORDER BY lc.country) AS countries
      FROM  licenses l
            JOIN license_countries lc ON lc.license_id = l.id
     WHERE  l.id > 80
  GROUP BY  l.id
```

what is the preferred way of sorting the result by the second column in a case-insensitive manner?

A straight `ORDER BY LOWER(countries)` is not possible, because the expressions in `ORDER BY` cannot refer to output column names. I can think of several ways to solve this, but I am not sure what the pros/cons are:

1. Wrap this query into a subquery and `SELECT *` from it; then `ORDER BY LOWER(countries)` would work fine.
2. Copy the `string_agg()` expression to `ORDER BY` but apply `LOWER()` to it.
3. Add another output column - same as the second line, but with `LOWER()` applied - then sort by that column.

I'm currently using the first option with the original query added in a CTE (`WITH` query). Is my assumption correct that this would typically have the least impact on performance?

---

I've run into similar situations before, usually involving something like `SELECT …, COUNT(*) as num_rows … ORDER BY COUNT(*) …`. This is short enough, so the duplication of the expression is not as conspicuous, but it now occurs to me that this may not be clean either.

Comment: I typically use 1) usually with a derived table, not a CTE and sometimes 2) (auto-completion in the SQL tool helps for that)